# Is it possible to capture the key associated with a datalist item upon selecting an item from the list?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, html-datalist

I have the below code to populate a search box with datalist items. The key of the datalist items is set to u.userID and the display is set to u.name. When an item is selected, I can get the u.name which is displayed. How can I get the underlying key associated with the item?

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="search" id="usersearch" list="userList" class="form-control" placeholder="Search user" 
              @keydown.enter="addUser(selectedUser)" v-model="selectedUser" v-on:input="changingUser($event)" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2"> <b-icon icon="search"></b-icon></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <datalist id="userList">
        <option v-for="u in users" :key="u.userID">{{ u.name }}</option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

```js
 methods: {
        addUser(user) {
            console.log(user);
        },
        changingUser(e) {
            if (!e.inputType) {
                this.addUser(this.selectedUser);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get the `key` from the selected `datalist.option` because the `input`-event does not link to the `<option>` in any way.

While not ideal, you could lookup the user by name, and access the `userID`:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    addUser(username) {
      const user = this.users.find(u => u.name === username)
      console.log('addUser ID', { userID: user?.userID })
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-get-selected-object-from-datalist?file=src/App.vue)